# what is the best way to set image to imageview

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I have created a relative layout. and align the imageview to the right of relativelayout. I set the background of relativelayout using selector. if i select thye relativelayout its color wil be green otherwise its color will be white. Now I want to set the image depending on the selection of scrollview. If scrollview is selected then i want to show imge1 if not then i want to show image2. How can I achieve this?

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selector">
    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**selector.xml**

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/grbk" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/grbk" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/grbk" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/whbk" />
</selector>
```

Thanks
Sunil[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create another selector for imageview and pass that selector as background to imageview.

**imageselector.xml**

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/arow_selected" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/arow_selected" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/arow_selected" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/arow_unselect" />
</selector>
```

**main.xml**

```
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/imageselector"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the same way as for background. You should add **android:duplicateParentState="true"**

```
<ImageView
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_selector"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

first set the color to all the list list view item and then put the selector in the list view ..i gess u know how to set the selector in list view

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion..
once i set the background to the imageview, then when i want to change the transparent, i can do nothing...after check some website, i found i need to set the imageview's resourse instead of background...